# Julia - UnderVarError

Tags: julia

The following code throws an "UndefVarError: g not defined"

```
function asdf()
if true
    f(t) = t
else 
    g(t) = t
    f(t) = g(t)
end
return f
end
w = asdf()
w(1)
```

but by replacing f(t) = g(t) by f = g, it works. Why?

Comment: I've never seen `else false` before. What does it mean?

Comment: Oh a typo from my side, it should just be "else". before it was an elseif statement but when educing the code to it's minimal expression, this escaped my eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15602.

The short recommendation is not to define a function that goes to method table twice in the body of a function. Instead use a variable to which you assign two different functions (with different names or anonymous) in branches.

What you should do until this is fixed is:

```
function asdf()
    if true
        f = t -> t
    else false
        g(t) = t
        f = g(t)
    end
    return f
end
```